# Pass a dynamic string value to vuelidate $v object - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

Trying to work out how to pass a string into to a vuelidate $v form element look up?

EG
`this.$v.appliance.required`

Where appliance would be a string.
I know that in Angular there is a getter `.get(...).required`
I've checked the [Vuelidate](https://vuelidate.netlify.com)docs and can't find anything similar.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given you asked this 9 months ago, you've probably figured it out already. But just in case anyone else bumps into the question...

You can specify the property key (i.e. the name of the property on the $v object as a string) using `bracket notation`.

Simply do `this.$v[appliance].required` instead of `this.$v.appliance.required`.

Bracket notation looks up the property by *key name* (your appliance string) on the object ($v), whereas dot notation looks for the *actual property* (appliance) on the parent object ($v).

Need a bit more info? The [property accessors page on the Mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) will give you more details.